# Focus is not working on top of card view

Tags: android-layout

I created on date edit text, on click on that date dialog will open, and user can select the date and this should not be editable. We are using external key board for doing this action.

By using the key board focus is not coming to this edit text,  but on touch this is working.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.eevoskos.robotoviews.widget.RobotoEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/etDate"
                    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Date"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:typeface="condensed" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

 android:focusable="false"
```

if I make focusable as true, edit text will become editable which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem a lot, For edit text you can use

```
 edTimeTaken.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

This does not let keyboard open.

Comment: this is not what I want, If we put InputType.TYPE_NULL , it is taking the any input. I want editText should be focusable but not editable.